# SPML client testing

Tags: saml, spml

I have created a SPML client. I need to verify whether it is  working perfectly. Please suggest me available open source SPML providers (Servers) to test the SPML client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project [keychain](https://java.net/projects/keychain) is a good spml gateway. It can be used to as a SPML complaint provider.